3D geometries not rendered in pgAdmin
I am new in GIS.
I created the below PostGIS code but pgAdmin is giving below error.
QGIS is also not showing any geometry when fetching this table in QGIS.
Can I get some real time 3D geometries or 3D shapefiles?
CREATE TABLE buildings (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100),
geom GEOMETRY(GeometryZ, 4326) -- GeometryZ indicates 3D geometry, 
4326 is the SRID for WGS 84
);
-- Add some sample data
INSERT INTO buildings (name, geom) VALUES
('Building 1', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 0, 10 0 0, 10 10 5, 
0 10 5, 0 0 0))', 4326)),
('Building 2', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((20 0 0, 30 0 0, 30 10 
10, 20 10 10, 20 0 0))', 4326)),
('Building 3', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 20 0, 10 20 0, 10 30 
8, 0 30 8, 0 20 0))', 4326)),
('Building 4', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((20 20 0, 30 20 0, 30 30 
6, 20 30 6, 20 20 0))', 4326)),
('Building 5', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((40 0 0, 50 0 0, 50 10 4, 
40 10 4, 40 0 0))', 4326));

-- Create a spatial index for faster spatial queries
CREATE INDEX buildings_geom_idx ON buildings USING GIST (geom);
SELECT * FROM buildings;


There is no problem, the geometry viewer of pgAdmin just does not render 3D geometries.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You have three different topics here, and no clear problem that needs solving. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one question (and be advised that Questions about locating data are closed here)

This has nothing to do with Oracle Spatial. Please remove that tag.

There's nothing wrong with geometry(GeometryZ,4326), nor with anything else about your code. I just don't think pgAdmin has a renderer that can handle those. All it does is check if geometries have the Z dimension:
if (geometry.hasZ) {
        geometries3D.push(geometry);

And if that's the case, it excludes them from rendering, adding that message:
  if (geometries3D.length > 0) {
    infoList.push(gettext('3D geometries not rendered.'));
  }

QGIS version 3.36.1 doesn't see a problem. 3D View is on the top bar, under View>3D Map Views>New 3D Map View:


One thing about rendering that in QGIS is you'll need to enable the 3D View symbols to see the depth. The No Symbols that's there by default means it's disabled:

You also need to switch from 4326 to a UTM zone if you want to use the 3D View. I went with 32618 just to show it works:
CREATE TABLE buildings (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100),
geom GEOMETRY(GeometryZ, 32618)
);
-- Add some sample data
INSERT INTO buildings (name, geom) VALUES
('Building 1', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 0, 10 0 0, 10 10 5, 0 10 5, 0 0 0))', 32618)),
('Building 2', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((20 0 0, 30 0 0, 30 10 10, 20 10 10, 20 0 0))', 32618)),
('Building 3', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 20 0, 10 20 0, 10 30 8, 0 30 8, 0 20 0))', 32618)),
('Building 4', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((20 20 0, 30 20 0, 30 30 6, 20 30 6, 20 20 0))', 32618)),
('Building 5', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((40 0 0, 50 0 0, 50 10 4, 40 10 4, 40 0 0))', 32618));

-- Create a spatial index for faster spatial queries
CREATE INDEX buildings_geom_idx ON buildings USING GIST (geom);
SELECT * FROM buildings;



it's perfectly running in QGIS, Can you recommend some resources for PostGIS , I need to cover all the patterns in 3D/4D geometry

@Shoaib There's the manual, plus some training material recommendations in the doc.
